# WordPress with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, wordpress

I'm running Windows 7 and SQL Server 2008 Express. I want to install WordPress to use MSSQL instead of MySQL. I'm following the installation instructions on [this page](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server). When I click the link to download WordPress, SourceForge says the file is unavailable. Is it still possible to install WordPress with MSSQL? If so, how do I get the download file? Or is there some other way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: [I found](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server) [these articles](http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress) [on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+sql+server)

Comment: I saw those too. However, I'm still not finding the right file to download or am have a horrible time trying to find a cohesive set of instructions to follow. I've got WordPress working with MySQL, but I'd really like to get it working with MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the plugin here, a newer version than what's (not) on sourceforge:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/

I can confirm it working on a site running 3.9.2, but I'm not sure about WP4.0.